# jQuery MultiSelect uncheck by Index, not by val()

Tags: jquery, multi-select

I'll try to make this sensible... 
Using jQuery multiselect checkbox plugin. Options are added dynamically via AJAX call.  When user selects an item/option and closes the selectbox, the item is added to the UI along with a "Remove" icon.  The icon has an ID added to it dynamically so that User can remove the item from the UI which I also want to uncheck from the closed selectbox.  The ID that's added is the "value" of the selected option so that I can associate the item on the UI with the option in the selectbox.  This works great when the Value is short (less than 2 words).  But when the value is larger than 2 words, I get an error: "unrecognized expression: checkbox[value=xxxxx]".  This error is thrown from jQuery:

```
Sizzle.error = function( msg ) {
    throw new Error( "Syntax error, unrecognized expression: " + msg );
};
```

Comparing the actual Value with the "msg", it appears the jQuery is truncating the ID after 2 words and so can't match it to any know selectBox Value.
Okay, so I decided to use the "index" of the selected item and add it to the "remove' icon (along with an identifer) which would associate it with the selected option in the Selectbox.  When removed from the UI, I strip the identifier and just use the Index.  My problem is that I can't uncheck the thing.  I've tried this:

```
$('select#'+cOption).multiselect("widget").find(":checkbox[index="+delVal+"]").each(function() {
                this.click();   // Remove check from deleted option
```

No error, just no uncheck.

I'd post the whole thing but it's quite large and somewhat complex.  Basically I just want to uncheck a selected option by Index rather than Value.

Comment: what is `delVal`?  the index or value?

Comment: As mentioned... "I strip the identifier and just use the Index".  It's an integer from 0-4 (5 selections, max).

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
$('select#'+cOption).multiselect("widget").find(":checkbox[index='"+delVal+"']").each(function() {
                this.click();  });
```

instead of

```
$('select#'+cOption).multiselect("widget").find(":checkbox[index="+delVal+"]").each(function() {
                this.click();
```